# NSAppleEventManager.shared().setEventHandler steal the focus

Tags: swift, macos, nsappleeventmanager

When register for url activation in my app with

```
NSAppleEventManager.shared().setEventHandler(self, andSelector: #selector(self.handleEvent(_:with:)), forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))
```

I'm getting the callback in my app when my app is stealing the focus of the user in the Mac, at the end of the activation of my func 'handleEvent()'.

I don't want my app to steal the focus since I'm running in the background, and the user doesn't even know why his current app lost her focus.

How can I set it to keep running without stealing the user's focus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I got no answer, I switched the methodology and used *DistributedNotificationCenter*
to communicate between 2 apps.

No focus stealing with this solution.